# Error in Object injection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am working on a Laravel 5.4 Project. I am facing an issue. I would like to know more about the issue.

Below code is working.

**PostController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DB;
use View;
use App\Model\Book;
use App\Model\Chapter;
use App\Model\Post;

class PostController extends Controller
{
      public function index(Book $book,Chapter $chapter)
      {
            $books = Book::all();
            $posts = Post::get_post($book,$chapter);

            $data = array(
                'posts'     => $posts,
                'books'       => $books,
                'section_id'  => ''
            );

            return View::make('posts')->with($data);
      }
}
```

Below code is creating error " *Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$book' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ')'* "

**PostController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DB;
use View;
use App\Model\Book;
use App\Model\Chapter;
use App\Model\Post;

class PostController extends Controller
{
      public function index(Book $book,Chapter $chapter)
      {
            $books = Book::all();
            $posts = Post::get_post(Book $book,Chapter $chapter); //issue is in this line

            $data = array(
                'posts'     => $posts,
                'books'       => $books,
                'section_id'  => ''
            );

            return View::make('posts')->with($data);
      }
}
```

Why this error is coming ?

Comment: public function index(Book $book,Chapter $chapter)() in this function from where you are geetting $book

Comment: I am getting this `$book` from Model. Thanks

Comment: if you are calling the models right so no need to pass again..

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this line:

```
$posts = Post::get_post(Book $book,Chapter $chapter); //issue is in this line
```

is that when you call function you don't type hint types. You should run function like this:

```
$posts = Post::get_post($book, $chapter);
```

Yes, you declare get_post function like this:

```
public static function get_post(Book $book,Chapter $chapter) 
{
  // do whatever you want here
}
```

but now when you call you don't use `Book` or `Chapter` anymore